# How to disable windows 7 keyboard shortcut for moving active window?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, productivity

Before windows 7, I was using an autohotkey script to positioning windows. Now, windows 7 has Win+Up/Down/Left/Right for moving the active window. There are few reasons I want to disable the built-in hot keys:

1. When my script is being used, built-in hot keys still work for a few types of windows like console and some service control window but not all of them. This inconsistency is hard to cope with.
2. I cannot stop using my script because it provides more ways of positioning and aligning windows, comparing to the built-in hot keys.

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity what more could you want besides left/right and full?

Comment: @Shawn: I use Win-Arrows to move/align the active window by boundaries of other visible windows. To think how useful it is, image you want to keep the calculator on the left side of a word document. A simple dock-to-right will leave you some unused desktop space in nowadays screens. Also, a built-in hot key has three possible outcomes(L/R/F), which IMHO is a very bad design because I believe human brain cannot unconsciously track three status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable Windows Snap, click on the `Start Orb` then type "`accessibility`", or part of it until you see `Ease of Access Center` listed, from here, click `Make the mouse easier to use`.

[image]

Under this, click on `Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen`.

[image]

And you are done, this disables both the snap with the mouse to the side and the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I saw this option before but could never relate it to keyboard. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I could not relate it neither. Good example for bad UI naming.